# Drake cmake Could NOT find Gurobi

Tags: c++, cmake, gurobi, drake

I use ubuntu 20.04 and I trying install Drake software.
I have got error while making with cmake  `cmake -DWITH_GUROBI=ON -DWITH_MOSEK=ON ../drake`:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindGurobi.cmake:13 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/dmitriy/git/drake/Gurobi_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/gurobi_c.h" cannot be
  read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:450 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Gurobi: Found unsuitable version ".;.", but required is
  exact version "9.5.1" (found Gurobi_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:391 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindGurobi.cmake:52 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:450 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dmitriy/git/drake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Did you install Gurobi?  The installation instructions can be found in the Gurobi section of this page: https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html

If yes, then please provide more details.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't install gurobi and that is reason. After installation of gurobi error disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Gurobi and error dosappeared.